# Getting SurfaceTexture pixels fast or trick with TextArea

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

I have the Qt realtime broadcasting chat application for Android (v 4.1, API 16), that sends H.264/AAC chunks to RTMP server.

For now, application uses `SurfaceView` for capturing frames from `Camera` and in `onPreviewFrame` function I encode frames to H.264 chunks and in other `Thread` I create RTMP chunks, that sending to RTMP server, as I wrote above.

Background is transparent (with `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag) and QML UI draws above `Camera`'s `SurfaceView` - works pretty well, without lags and other. But, when I tried to use QML's `TextArea` (for writing chat messages), that also above `SurfaceView`, there is a very long delays on some devices (and not on Samsung's) when I press on any key on Android's virtual keyboard, that did this app absolutely unusable. For example, I type "LAG" on keyboard, and there is 3-4 second delay between showing every symbol in `TextArea` ))): `SurfaceView` and broadcast works without lags.

So, dear developers, what I shall do to solve this problem?

For now, I moved `Camera`'s preview to `SurfaceTexture` and draw it using Qt's `QSGGeometryNode`, but there is another problem: how to read pixels from `SurfaceTexture` more efficient? Is it possible to make performance faster or similar to `onPreviewFrame`? May be I am moving in wrong direction and I can do some trick with `TextArea`?

Thanks!